# Why did I receive "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'" when working through AWS Lambda Python Tutorial?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I received the following error, where 'requests' is the module I am trying to import:

```
Response {
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: cb6630ea-1e0b-4b53-a302-13223443123c Version: $LATEST
09 Dec 2021 03:59:09,177 [INFO] (/var/runtime/bootstrap.py) main started at epoch 1639022349177
09 Dec 2021 03:59:09,178 [INFO] (/var/runtime/bootstrap.py) init complete at epoch 1639022349179
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, ensure that the module you are trying to import (in this case 'requests') is at the same path level as lambda_function.py.

It was in the packages folder, so you should move it up to the same level as lambda_function.py. [image: Move module to same level]